# Find $\oint_\Gamma \frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}dz$ where $\Gamma$ is a positevly oriented unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Find $$\oint_\Gamma \frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}dz$$ where $\Gamma$ is a positevly oriented unit circle.

My attempt:

$$\oint_\Gamma \frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}dz=\oint_\Gamma \frac{\cos z}{z(z-\sqrt8 i)(z+\sqrt8 i)}$$

Now I apply residue theorem to get:

$$2\pi i (Res(f,0)+Res(f,\sqrt8 i)+Res(f,-\sqrt8 i))=2\pi i(1/8-\frac{\cos(\sqrt8 i)}{8})$$

But I don't like this answer. 
Is is possible to compute this integral using Cauchy Integral Formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\pm\sqrt{8}i$ are not in the unit disk. Hence the answer is simply $$2\pi i Res(f,0)=\frac{i\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed that :), is there another way of computing this integral? I tried parametrizing, but it seems complicated.

Comment: I don't think so, the parametrization will be extremely complicated. Residue/Cauchy Formula is straightforward.

Comment: To use cauchy, I will need to split into partial fractions and use $f(z)=1/2\pi i\int \frac{f(z_0)}{z_0-z}dz_0$